# downloadHandler (Shiny) misinterprets slash in the users' path name

Tags: r, shiny

I try to use downloadHadler for saving a content from Shiny applications. It saves always in the Downloads directory of the computer. Every path name that I enter is interpreted as a part of the file name with "_" instead "/". May be the reason is the German keyboard? Here is just example from r with addition of the path "H:/ShinyResults/":

```
## Only run examples in interactive R sessions
if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")
  )

  server <- function(input, output) {
    # Our dataset
    data <- mtcars

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("H:/ShinyResults/", "data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(data, file)
      },
      contentType = "text/csv"
    )
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

The resulting file is H__ShinyResults_data-2018-08-13.csv in the Downloads directory. I run Shiny in "run External" mode.

Thank you in advance,

Yuri

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It always will save in your default download directory. You cannot put a full local path: this path might work on your machine but never will on mine for instance (since I'm on Linux).

`downloadHandler` takes a `filename` not a path.